# Standard deviation of the **difference scores** is √2 times as large as standard deviation of each group

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, standard-deviation, standard-error

In reading a blog post [**HERE**](https://www.r-bloggers.com/why-within-subject-designs-require-fewer-participants-than-between-subject-designs/), I encountered a comment which I'm trying to validate here.

Specifically, the the blog says:

In a paired-samples t-test design, the population standard deviation of the **difference scores (i.e., scores resulting from subtracting scores in each group from that in the other group)** is **√2** times as large as **the population standard deviation of each group (i.e., pre-test group and the post-test group)?**

Is this statement accurate, if yes why?

Comment: It's only true in the special case where the scores in each group are uncorrelated. If you take into account a non-zero correlation, then the variance of the difference could be much smaller or much larger than this

Comment: @JakeWestfall, thanks very much. But why is this so? Could you please provide some formal answer? And I can upvote.

Comment: $N_W = N_B(1-ρ)/2$ copied from lined article. Is it correct? I think $N_W = N_B$ if correlation = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only true in the special case where the scores in each group are uncorrelated and have the same standard deviation. If you take into account a non-zero correlation, then the standard deviation of the difference could be much smaller or much larger than this.

To explain, let's call the variables representing the scores from each group $X$ and $Y$. A [basic fact from the algebra of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties) is that
$$
\text{var}(X - Y) = \text{var}(X) + \text{var}(Y) - 2\text{cov}(X, Y),
$$
where $\text{cov}(X,Y)$ means the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. The standard deviation of the difference $X-Y$ is, of course, the square root of the equation above. So in the special case where $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated (so that $\text{cov}(X,Y)=0$) and where $X$ and $Y$ have the same variance (so that $\text{var}(X)=\text{var}(Y)=\sigma^2$), then the standard deviation reduces to
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\text{var}(X - Y)} &= \sqrt{\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 - 0}
\\ &= \sqrt{2}\sigma.
\end{aligned}
$$
However, in general, the higher (i.e., more positive) $\text{cov}(X,Y)$ is, the lower the standard deviation of the difference will be, and conversely the lower (i.e., more negative) $\text{cov}(X,Y)$ is, the higher the standard deviation of the difference will be.